# How to read read the contents of a text file in a separate Java package in a file

Tags: java, user-interface, text-extraction

I have a package with a GUI, and in this GUI I need to  read a text file (call it list.txt) that may look like

8:00am something

9:00am somethingelse

1:00pm something different

With each time/event on a separate line.

How do I read each line separately and extract the time portion from each line?  What I need to accomplish is to compare times in a list like this to a range of times I have previously determined, and reprint the list with only events/times in that range, but I'm not sure on how to read it line by line.

How does the question not make sense?  All I am asking is how to take a textFile (one written in a separate java package) and how to basically read it one line at a time and take the time portion from each line.  The time is always at the start of each line.  I'm sorry, but I don't know how to be more clear on that, that is about all there is to it.

And The user provides the text file name via GUI application, as well as a time range.  But that part I have down.

Comment: You don't know how to read line by line or you don't know what the path is for a file in a different package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `java.io.BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method to read file line-by-line.
- Use `java.lang.String`'s `indexOf()` method to locate the first space.
- Use `java.lang.String`'s `substring()` method to extract before and after the space.